# Scale subplots in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a simple and direct question:
Can I scale-up or scale-down (horizontally and vertically) the subplots in Matlab so that the plots may look a bit bigger and clear?

If yes then kindly let me know.

Thanks

```
figure()
subplot(2,2,1)
subplot(2,2,2)
subplot(2,2,3)
subplot(2,2,4)
```

[image]

Comment: Does [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125099/how-can-i-set-subplot-size-in-matlab-figure) help?

Comment: Use `subaxis` from FileExchange. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685092/how-to-reduce-the-borders-around-subplots-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

try using something like this:

```
figure,
subplot(4,4,[1:2 5:6])
plot()
subplot(4,4,[3:4 7:8])
plot()
subplot(4,4,[9:10 13:14])
plot()
subplot(4,4,[11:12 15:16])
plot()
```

greetz